# PHP get ISO week number for a date whose starting day is other than Monday

Tags: php, date, strtotime, iso8601

According to the ISO standar, the 52nd week of 2013, when the week starts on Saturday, starts 2013-12-28 and ends 2014-01-03 (inclusive).

**Code:**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("2013-W52-6"));//prints 2013-12-28
```

Now, I am trying to figure out the inverse using PHP. If I have the date 2014-01-03, how to know the ISO weeknumber of that date if the week starts on Saturday?

Comment: You can't redefine the [`ISO-8601` weeknumber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO-8601#Week_dates), it has a pretty clear, unambiguous definition. You can give a date _another_ weeknumber by defining your own standard of week numbering, which isn't the same and will not be `ISO-8601`, and you'll have to decide whether you want the offset to go forward of backward in time, or provide custom rules by looking at the definition in the original. Which way should it go?

Comment: How can a week start on Saturday?

Comment: So from any date, you want its week number? I don't understand why my answer does not work?

Comment: @Wrikken, Fabien Warniez Sorry, I was confused. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DateTime class:

1. createFromFormat() to create the object based on the string you have
2. then format('W')

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = "2013-12-28";
$dayofyear = date("z", $date);

$week = floor($dayofyear / 7) + 1;

// I assume week starts with Monday (I think as ISO does?)
// so only weeks that start on sunday will count as "week 0" instead of "week 1"
// I could be wildly wrong, adjust according to your needs
$first_day = date("w", date("Y", $date) . "-01-01");
if ($first_day == 6)
  --$week;

echo $week;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$date = "2013-12-28";
$date_array = explode("-", $date);
$date  = mktime(0, 0, 0, $date_array[1], $date_array[2], $date_array[0]);
$week_number  = date('W', $date);
echo $week_number;
```

Something like this.

Comment: That's overkill. Both date() and DateTime can handle Y-m-d formatted dates without any manipulation required.

Comment: I guess DateTime objects and createFromFormat works in PHP 5+ only (not PHP 4).